# Can't ping any computer on LAN (including myself)

Tags: windows-10, firewall, ping

I can't ping anyone on local network, only my own router (default gateway).

When i try to ping myself (ping xxx.xxx.x.xxx) it throws "General Failure."
When i try to ping other computers it throws "Request timeout."

My firewall settings:

1. Printers and files ICMPv-4(In) is enabled for private, public, domain + enabled edge traversal
2. Printers and files ICMPv-4(Out) is enable for private, public, domain + enabled edge traversal

Everything else is default.

I even tried to disable firewall for both private and public networks completely but it still behaves the same way. Also tried to enable 40-56bit coding and disabled password protection.

My question is: How can i make my pc ping others and myself in LAN ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you have internet? Did you do anything out of the ordinary on the computer when this happened?

Comment: yes, i do have internet, and no, didn't do anything unusual with my pc.